# Passport Error - Strategy.ParseErrorResponse

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Hi there I've been trying to find a solution for this error for 2 days and to no avail! I have already searched on Stack Overflow. The errors are simply not related to mine. Here is the stack trace I am receiving.

```
Error
    at Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/Users/jeremy/projects/thinkful_capstone_2/node_modules/passport-facebook/lib/strategy.js:196:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/Users/jeremy/projects/thinkful_capstone_2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:376:16)
    at /Users/jeremy/projects/thinkful_capstone_2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
    at /Users/jeremy/projects/thinkful_capstone_2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (/Users/jeremy/projects/thinkful_capstone_2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/jeremy/projects/thinkful_capstone_2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

also here is my code:

```
const path = require('path');
// const Strategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
// const { User } = require('../models/usermodel.js');
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));


passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});



router.get('/', passport.authenticate('facebook'), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    console.log(req.user);
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/adwall.html'));
});


module.exports = router;
```

any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Edit: Also I added this strategy in my server file:

here is the strategy for the facebook auth that I am using in a different file called server.js:

```
passport.use(new Strategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/facebook/auth/cb'
},
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        return cb(null, profile);
    }));
```

Here is the link to the github project: 
https://github.com/jeremytaylor7/wallaby-ads-project

Comment: sorry guys I forgot to add, that the error comes up only when I add passport.authenticate as middleware @ the router for '/'

Comment: Same thing here, if I add the middleware to '/' i get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten something very important.

When you do `passport.authenticate('facebook')...`

it will look for facebook strategy which you have not defined.

http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook look here to configure new strategy.

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Also maybe have `app.use(passport.initialize())` and `app.use(passport.session())` below where you defined the session.

Comment: Thank you for your reaching out! I forgot to include that I have added the strategy in a different file which is my server file called server.js